# iPhone: How to use a UITableView as a drop-down menu

Tags: iphone

How do I get UITableView to display as drop-down list?

I want to enable selection from a list of items. Since picker view takes up a lot of space and I have already used once in the same app, I was just wondering if UITableView can be used for displaying a drop-down list as it will take scant space.

And also the list gets populated from a database which lends itself to editing by the user from the interface.

Thanks in advance.

Sayeed

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I want to enable selection from a list of items. Since picker view takes up a lot of space and I have already used once in the same app, I was just wondering if UITableView can be used for displaying a drop-down list as it will take scant space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you're trying to do something with your UITableView as the last one in the following image: (simply making a selection of one item)

[image]

I suggest you to [push](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated:) your "drop down" UITableView into your UINavigationController.
Apple has [a reference guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW12) ready also.

Hope you'll see where I'm trying to pointing you :-)